# How to use url alias in views for taxonomy terms?

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms, path-aliases

On a Drupal 7 site with [pathauto](https://drupal.org/project/pathauto) installed I'm using a view to show all taxonomy terms of a given node. The terms are linked to the term's page. The problem is, that the path of those terms does not use the url alias' that are set for the terms. Is there a way (without programmatically rewrite the view) to use alias in a view?

I know about the [globalredirect](https://drupal.org/project/globalredirect) module, but a redirect is not a clean solution here, in my opinion. And I do not understand why the pathes aren't replaced by there aliases in a view, can someone explain please?

Comment: Are you using drupal 7 with pathauto?

Comment: @KristerAndersson Yes, thank you, I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a kind of workaround but
I thinks the simplest solution for you would be to use the module: 
[TVI: Taxonomy View Integrator](https://www.drupal.org/project/tvi)

Then when when you modify the terms vocabulary you can use a view to replace the default page default view:  the url alias of the term alias would call your view.